# Can we send value to an input field in an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

Can we send variable to an input field that is in an iFrame ?

I want to build a auto-login script for Google Analytics and would like to load the content of this page (https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginBoxAuth) to an iframe and then fill the fields with user / pass.

Can we achieve this in jQuery or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, browser security will prevent that as your site is not on the domain google.com. See [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: Yeah sound that some script like postMessage need to have the script both installed on host and remote server. :(